# How to generate a matrix with certain conditions

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, random, sampling

I want to generate a $n \times n$ matrix.

1. I want the diagonal entries to be all 0
2. I want a random choice of matrix elements with 0 or 1.
3. The probability of having a 1 as a matrix element is $1/m$ and the probability of having a 0 as a matrix element is $1-1/m$.

I used the following command but it is wrong.

```
A[n_, m_] :=Table[If[i == j, 0,RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[m],{n,n}]]]
```

And I tried to test this command with n=4, m=0.4 but it didn't work.

Could anyone kindly tell me how to do this please?
Thank you!

Comment: For a start, your code seems to set the diagonal elements to 1 rather than zero.

Comment: Same question posted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1623288).

Comment: tiffany, please go [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, so you can easily access your question.

Answer (score 5):

Binary random variables are often modeled using the `BernoulliDistribution`. You can use the function `RandomVariate` to get a matrix of such variables.

```
mat = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[0.9], {5, 5}]; 
mat - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mat]]
% // MatrixForm
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

You can change the `0.9` to any value (this is your `m`). The second line sets all the diagonal elements to zero.

It's easy enough to make this into a function:

```
makeMat[n_, m_] := (mat = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[m], {n, n}]; 
                    mat - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mat]])
```

Then the above example is `makeMat[5, 0.9]`

Comment: Thank you bill s
How will the command be if I do not restrict what n and m be?
For example, I would like to generate a set of commands which I can replace m and n easily by any number.

Comment: @tiffany, just do `With[{n = 8, m = 3}, (# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]]) &[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1/m], {n, n}]]]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use weight option in  `RandomChoice`

```
n = 5;
m = 2;
mat = RandomChoice[{1/m, 1 - 1/m} -> {1, 0}, {n, n}];
(mat - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal@mat]) // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Altho using the `BernoulliDistribution[]` is best, this is likely to be more easy to read for someone who is not accustomed to discrete probability distributions.

Answer (score 4):

Since all the simple answers have been given, here is a `SparseArray[]` solution that may be useful if you want to generate large matrices without storing unneeded zero entries:

```
tiffany[n_Integer?Positive, m_] :=
    SparseArray[{j_, k_} /; j != k && RandomReal[] < 1/m :> 1, {n, n}]
```

As an example:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom["tiffany"]; tiffany[7, 2.5] // Normal]
   {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m = 2;
n = 5;
rnd[x_] := If[RandomReal[{0, 1}] < 1/m, 1, 0];
t = Table[rnd[x_]*(1 - KroneckerDelta[i, j]), {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
t // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Thank you Vsevolod A.
How will the command be if I do not restrict what n and m be?

Comment: @tiffany you set `m` and `n` in the first two lines...

Comment: Just `rnd := If[RandomReal[{0, 1}] < 1/m, 1, 0];` will do, since the function never uses its argument.